# PHP To Calculate AgrregateRating out of 5 stars

Tags: php

So I have the following values of Number of likes on a item and Number of Dislikes on a item i can combine the two figures to get the total number of votes.

```
$likes = 4300; //number of likes
$dislikes = 8000; //number of dislikes
$total = $likes + $dislikes; //total number of votes by combining the two figures together
```

But I how can I take these values and create a AggregateRating out of 5 stars for a schema markup I am doing.

Comment: Not sure what your last sentence means, especially *create a AggregateRating out of 5 stars for a schema markup I am doing*

Comment: So i need to take the above values and work out an average number of likes and dislikes to make into a rating of 5 stars for example so based of the average number of likes and dislikes it will make the rating either 1 star or 5 stars etc

Comment: I guess you can't, only using `likes` and `dislikes` doesn't represent a 5-star-rating. You'd need to know how many 1-star, 2-star ... ratings there are

Comment: Yes but the average of the total number of likes / dislikes will be the value i am after. the value just can't be less than 1 or higher than 5.

Comment: So a "like" is a 5-star-rating and a "dislike" is a 1-star-rating? `$average = ($likes*5 + $dislikes*1) / ($likes + $dislikes);`

Comment: @kerbholz yes thats awesome :) works how would you reduce the size it says "2.3983739837398" where as i would prefer it just say 2.3 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a "like" represents a "5-star-rating" and a "dislike" represents a "1-star-rating" you can get the average like so:

```
$likes = 4300;
$dislikes = 8000;
$average = ($likes*5 + $dislikes*1) / ($likes + $dislikes);

echo $average;
```

Will output `2.3983739837398`

You can use `number_format()` to limit the decimals:

```
echo number_format($average,1);
```

Will output `2.4`